# How can css selector nth-child apply to an array?

Tags: css

I need to format a few `<td>` in css.

Instead of

```
td:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(7){
    padding-right:15px;
}
```

Can we do something like `td:nth-child(4,6,7)`?

Comment: Which CSS spec are you using?  This is possible in CSS4, and a little more difficult in CSS3

Comment: Might be better to just add a common class to those TD elements.

Answer (score 0):

In css4, you can use the `:matches` pseudoselector

> The :matches pseudo-class is described as a functional pseudo-class by the official CSS Selectors Level 4 specifications. It doesn't serve any purpose in itself except making some complex selectors lighter by allowing them to be grouped. In a way, we can think as :matches as syntactic sugar.

```
:matches(:nth-child(4), :nth-child(5), :nth-child(6)) td {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Note, you may have to use the following vendor prefixes

- Mozilla: `-moz-any`
- Chrome: `-webkit-any`

Here is the browser support

- Chrome: 12+
- Firefox: 5+
- Opera: 15+
- IE: Not supported

References

http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/matches-any-pseudo-class/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/

http://red-team-design.com/meet-the-css4-selectors/

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You might use :nth-child(an+b), where a and b are constants and 'n' is a variable.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp.

This only helps for repeating columns that can be calculated using this form.